# Convert string value back to GUID value

Tags: c#, guid

i have a guid value that i store in my hidden variable. 
say for eg (303427ca-2a5c-df11-a391-005056b73dd7)

now how do i convert the value from this hidden field back to GUID value (because the method i would be calling expects a GUID value).

thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the overloaded constructor:

```
try
{
  Guid guid = new Guid("{D843D80B-F77D-4655-8A3E-684CC35B26CB}");
}
catch (Exception ex) // There might be a more appropriate exception to catch
{
  // Do something here in case the parsing fails.
}
```

Comment: this definitely would be the simplest method

Comment: @espais: Yes, I am sometimes scared when I see how easy thoses things have become.

Comment: Worth noting that there is no TryParse available for GUID so you may want to wrap this in a try/catch block.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Kelly for pointing that out. I updated my answer to add this advice.

Answer (score 3):

You are making it pretty easy on an attacker by storing the Guid in a string.  Trivial to find back in, say, the paging file.  Store it in a Guid and kill two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 2):

```
    string strGuid;
    strGuid = (your guid here);
    Guid guid = new Guid(strGuid);
```

[For more info, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Guid has a constructor for string Guids.

```
Guid guid = new Guid(myStringGuid);
```

Answer (score 2):

new Guid(myHiddenFieldString)

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done simply as following:

```
Guid MyGuid = new Guid(stringValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET4 onwards you can also use:

```
Guid myGuid = Guid.Parse(myGuidString);
```

Just a matter of coding preference, but some people find this more intuitive.